# How can I change the height of my whole grid and reduce the height of cells equally?

Tags: html, css

I have a css grid I'm using in my webpage, the code for which is below. I want to change the height of this grid so that there isn't so much room between the bottom/top of the grid and the elements in my grid.

However when I add a `height: 100px` property to my grid class, it reduces the height of the cells unevenly. I want to be able to change this so that the cells of my grid are reduces equally, and therefore the horizontal line between my grid cells is evenly spaced.

I'm not sure if doing this actually has any tangible difference, but it just seems wrong that the two rows of grids have unequal heights when I specify a height for the whole grid.

```
.title-grid {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 1fr);
            grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
            grid-column-gap: 0px;
            grid-row-gap: 0px;
            border-bottom: #bfbfbf solid 1px;
        }
```

Before adding height property:
[image]

After adding height property (red line is roughly where I want the dividing horizontal line to be)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can check the code I have uploaded, I have set the height of div
and my grid cell is of same height and width.

```css
.grid-container {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: auto;
            background-color: #2196F3;
            padding: 10px;
            height: 15vh;
            grid-template-rows: 5vh 5vh 5vh;
            grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
        }

        .grid-item {
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
            border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
            text-align: center;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <h1>Grid Elements</h1>

    <p>A Grid Layout must have a parent element with the <em>display</em> property set to <em>grid</em> or
        <em>inline-grid</em>.</p>

    <p>Direct child element(s) of the grid container automatically becomes grid items.</p>

    <div class="grid-container">
        <div class="grid-item">1</div>
        <div class="grid-item">2</div>
        <div class="grid-item">3</div>
        <div class="grid-item">4</div>
        <div class="grid-item">5</div>
        <div class="grid-item">6</div>
        <div class="grid-item">7</div>
        <div class="grid-item">8</div>
        <div class="grid-item">9</div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```